# Where to place the "which clause"?

Tags: relative-clauses

1. Yut Nori is the most popular game in Korea.
2. Yut Nori is a traditional board game played in Korea, especially during Korean New Year.

I made two kinds of sentences:

1. Yut Nori is the most popular game in my country **which** is a traditional board game played especially during Korean New Year.
2. Yut Nori **which** is a traditional board game played especially during Korean New Year is the most popular game in my country.

I don't know where to put the '**which clause**'. Or are both the sentences wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the relative clause if you wish to add extra information, you place the clause after the object:

- Yut Nori, **which** is a traditional game, especially played during Korean New Year, is the most popular game in my country.

You could also union these clauses using "**and**":

- Yut Nori is a traditional game, especially played during the Korean New Year and it is the most popular game in my country.